# What is the name for this type of diagram?

Tags: terminology

When studying an agglutinative language, one sometimes encounters the following type of helpful diagram, which labels a sentence according to the grammatical function of each constitutive element.

Here is a (poorly designed) mock-up of the kind of diagram I am referring to:
[image: Mock-up diagram]

**Does this type of diagram have a name? If so, what is it called?**

I would like to find a program (or LaTeX package) that can be used to quickly create these diagrams, but I am not sure what to be searching for!

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular designation for such diagrams. Perhaps you will need to come with your own. I agree that they are helpful for illustrating the syntax and morphosyntax of such languages.

Comment: Isn't this really the same as an [interlinear gloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss), just that in the latter the items are vertically aligned rather than having lines connecting?

Comment: For interlinear glossing in LaTeX, there is [`gb4e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e)/[`cgloss`](http://www.let.uu.nl/~alexis.dimitriadis/personal/latex/), [`linguex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/linguex), and [`expex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex). See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77937/32888) on TeX.SX.

Comment: If I were to guess at a term or have to coin one myself I would pick something like "template diagram" or "agglutination diagram". Agglutinating languages generally fit certain pieces together in certain fixed orders, the pattern in linguistics is often called a "template" and the places where morphemes fit into the template are usually called "slots".

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut I think you're correct, and I initially looked into glossing as a solution, although the type of diagram I've reproduced is useful because it maintains the "look" of the word (i.e. no awkward hyphenation) while still showing which characters make up the morpheme.

Comment: @Adam Liter Thank you for those links, I will see if I can find anything suitable in those packages!

Comment: You won't find anything in those packages that does anything like the picture in your question here. Those packages were designed for interlinear glossing. If you really want a diagram like the one you have, then the easiest/best way is probably to use TikZ. Though not exactly the same thing, my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128096/32888) to this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128064/32888) might be a useful place to start if you do want a diagram like the one depicted in your question.

Comment: @AdamLiter Wow! That answer is definitely a good point of departure, although it anticipates my question over on tex.stackexchange.com and leaves this one open. As such, I suppose that I would consider hippietrail's comment to be close to an answer (insofar as it builds off of Tim Osborne's suggestion that no established designation exists). Thanks to those who have commented here!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with users Gaston Ümlaut, Adam Liter; the closest thing to this is, I think, a gloss.

I use [expex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex).

Example:

```
\usepackage{expex}

\pex                                   %itemizes this paragraph (until \xe) as (1), (2) ...
\begingl                               % begin gloss
\gla Fliegen fliegen Fliegen nach //   % end all three lines with a double forward slash
\glb flies fly flies after //          % this line aligns with gla
\glft "Flies fly after flies" //       % this one doesn't
\endgl
\xe
```